# Wordpress Thumbnail on hover the link

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, hover

Can anyone help?

How can I display a thumbnail of a photo in wordpress after hovering a link?

Comment: Hi, did you tried anything, please share the code. So that we can see whats can be change in that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.